# How to debug django in spyder

Tags: django, spyder

I have a django project which I would like to start in debug mode so I can use breakpoints in spyder to see what is happening.

However I do not know how to start the manage.py runserver in debug mode in spyder.

Unfortunately I am stuck with spyder for this (unfortunate because I know how to do it in vs code).

Can anybody help me?